# Right aligned lines mismatch when enabling microtype

Tags: spacing, koma-script, microtype, scrlayer-scrpage

I have a document which has a right aligned two line header. Said header is created using `scrlayer-scrpage`. When I also try to enable the `microtype` package the two lines do not line up at the right and the second line is shifted a bit to the left. A minimal working example is provided below:

```latex
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

% CONFIGURATION
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont} % reset \slshape

\ohead{
| Test ()\\
| Test ()%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{flushright}
    | Test ()\\
    | Test ()%
  \end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

This occurs in PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX as far as I can tell. Removing the line which changes the font for the head does not remove the issue though it is far less noticeable. The `lua-visual-debug` packages helps visualize the boxes a bit better.

Strangely the error does not occur in the body. For now I could revert to getting along without the microtype package though if it is an error on my side I would like to get it fixed and if it is a bug inside the `microtype` or `scrlayer-scrpage` I would like to report a bug to help them fix it.

[image: misaligned lines in header]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no error on your part, but it's not a bug either. The misalignment is due to the  fact that `scrlayer-scrpage` inserts a `\strut` at the end of the header (to ensure uniform line spacing), which prevents `microtype` (or rather the respective engine) from seeing the end-of-line. There are two possible workarounds:

- Either disable protrusion in the first line, too, by inserting a strut:

  ```
  \ohead{%
  | Test ()\strut\\
  | Test ()%
  }
  ```
- Or reconstruct the protrusion by means of the primitive `\rightmarginkern` (which is available in all three engines):

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \newdimen\right@margin
  \newcommand*\protruderight[1]{%
    \vbox{\everypar{}%
      \setbox\@tempboxa\vbox{\noindent#1}%
      \unvbox\@tempboxa \setbox\@tempboxa=\lastbox
      \global\right@margin=\rightmarginkern\@tempboxa
    }%
    #1\kern\right@margin
  }
  \makeatother

  \ohead{%
  | Test ()\\
  | Test (\protruderight{)}%
  }
  ```

[`luatex` offers the primitive `\protrusionboundary`, which is supposed to simplify this, but I actually couldn't get it to work -- even the example in the doc doesn't seem to work as advertised.]